# tensorflow.js Pauses Working While Browser Window Is Invisible

Tags: gpu, cpu, background-process, tensorflow.js

I'm working on tensorflow.js examples. After fit function executed, epoches starts working without any problem.

But when i minimize browser window or open another tab or open another program window, Epoches pauses working and when open browser tensorflow.js example again, it continues to fit and epoches logs to the console.

My system is Windows 10, i tried Chrome, Firefox and Edge with same state.

I tried both CPU and CPU but nothing changed.

I googled and searched on stackoverflow but nobody reported this issue. And then i check and reset my power management settings but nothing changed.

At documents of tensorflow.js i can't find about this setting.

What may i do to tensorflow.js continues to fit and epoches logs to the console while browser minimized, etc.

My script code like below:

---

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
 <!-- Get latest version at https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs -->
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"> 
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="output_field"></div>
 </body>
 <script>
 async function learnLinear(){
  const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));
  const optimizer = tf.train.adam(0.1);
  model.compile({
   loss: 'meanSquaredError',
   metrics: ['accuracy'],
   optimizer: optimizer
  });

  const xs = tf.tensor2d([-40, -10, 0, 8, 15, 22, 38], [7, 1]);
  const ys = tf.tensor2d([-40, 14, 32, 46, 59, 72, 100], [7, 1]);

  const history = await model.fit(xs, ys, {
  epochs: 500,
    callbacks:{
        onEpochEnd: async(epoch, logs) =>{
            console.log("Epoch: " + epoch + " Loss: " + logs.loss);
            }
        }
  });

  document.getElementById('output_field').innerText =
   model.predict(tf.tensor2d([100.0], [1, 1]));
 }

 learnLinear();
 </script>
<html>
```

Comment: Browsers only put full resources for open tabs to prevent battery drain etc on laptops / mobile devices etc. This is working as intended. You must have the tab open to be working at full speed. I believe it will work when not in focus but much slower - this is a browser level thing and is applied to all JS not just machine learning situations

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I also tried to wait a lot of time for is it still running in the background but slowly but it is not continues for epoch works. I wait this simple example for 30-40 minutes but it still seems paused. But i will wait 2-3 hours not and test.

Comment: @JasonMayes i started my script and then each epoch logs to console each 1-2 second(s). And than i minimize browser and waited 2-3 hours. I maximized browser again but it continued from last epoch log :/ I don't understand why this happens :(

Comment: It is a browser decision to the best of my knowledge. Doing any intensive work in a tab it should be in focus or visible no matter if machine learning or not.

Comment: @JasonMayes i researched about this issue for reason and it is exactly as is what you wrote. The examples of another sources pause occures at all of them. I'm searching for tu solve this but can't find for now.

Comment: I dont think it is possible as it is a browser level decision, not something you can change as far as I know.

Comment: @JasonMayes i tested with brain.js . It is working in the background. And so, it may be a tensorflow.js problem. I will continue on brain.js for not. Thanks.